# Matlab: mask/create a circular roi knowing its origin point with a certain radius

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Just a quick question. I've an image and I've extracted a certain point (feature), I know the coordinates of that point in every frame.

Say x1 and y1.

I need a circular ROI form that point on the image with a radius that I chose.

I tried impoly and roipoly - not sure how to use either of these when I know the point in the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you know the coordinates of the center of the ROI along with the radius, you can modify a bit the code provided by @Jonas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651778/matlab-how-do-i-crop-out-a-circle-from-an-image) to create a circular mask in a quite efficient way.

Example:

```
clc;clear

Im = imread('coins.png');

[rNum,cNum,~] = size(Im);

%// Define coordinates and radius
x1 = 60;
y1 = 100;
radius = 40;

%// Generate grid with binary mask representing the circle. Credit to Jonas for original code.
[xx,yy] = ndgrid((1:rNum)-y1,(1:cNum)-x1);
mask = (xx.^2 + yy.^2)<radius^2;

%// Mask the original image
Im(mask) = uint8(0);

imshow(Im)
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to see only the outer edge of the ROI to see the center, add a logical condition with some tolerance for the radius of a smaller circle. Something like this:

```
mask = (xx.^2 + yy.^2)<radius^2 & (xx.^2 + yy.^2)>(radius-tol)^2;
```

With a `tol` of 2 it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Excellent stuff! Many thanks! Is there any way to plot this mask without the fill. i.e. just the out boundary of the mask circle. I need to run this on lots of data so it will be quicker to observe whether my mask is at the right location. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful. Sorry just a last question. Any idea how I can use a binary mask given the information I've for the mask in your code. I want to sue this function createMask - How?

Comment: newMask = createMask (mask, Im);

Comment: My pleasure! I'm not sure to understand what you want sorry. Since the code does not use [imroi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imroi.html) objects it does not have a `createMask` method. However the array `mask` is the exact same thing you would obtain by using the `createMask` method, i.e. an array filled with 0s and 1s.

Comment: But I'm getting Undefined function 'createMask' for input arguments of type 'uint16'.

Comment: You're right. But what if I want to "retrieve this mask" by = mask.*Im; so I can perform something on the original ROI from the image?

Comment: To be more clear. I need all this in a variable "Im(mask) = uint8(0);"