# Finding the area of the black spots in a circle MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is it possible to find the area of the black pixelation of an area within a circle? in other words I want to find the number of pixels (the area) of the RGB 0,0,0 (black pixels) within the circle. I do not want the areas of the white pixels (1,1,1) within the circle. I also have a radius of the circle if that helps. Here is the image:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
BW2= H(:,:) <0.45 ;%& V(:,:)<0.1;
aa=strel('disk',5);

closeBW = imclose(BW2,aa);
figure, imshow(closeBW)
imshow(closeBW)
viscircles([MYY1 MYX1], round(MYR2/2))
```

MYY1,MYX2, and the other values are calculated by my program. How can I find the area of the black pixelation in my circle?

Comment: You could try creating a temporary image that is just the pixels inside the circle, then use regionprops()

Comment: @willpower2727 How could I create a temporary image of what is in the circle?

Comment: While it is probably overkill, you could create a vector with all of the values inside of the circle, then create a histogram using `h=histogram(PTS)`.  Since black and white are the only two pixel values you can then get the resulting number of black and white pixels by looking at the contents of bins 1 and 2 in the histogram using `h.Values(1)` and `h.Values(2)` respectively.  If that is a reasonable solution to the problem I can work out the rest of the necessary code.

Comment: in response to @willpower2727 you can get the pixels in a circle by following the [steps at this link](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_create_a_circle.3F) about creating a circle.  Once you know the pixels covered by the circle you can copy them to a new array and use the either of the above solutions or any number of other mechanisms to get a count of black and white pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

1) Calculate the total # of black pixels in your original image (let's call it `A`).

2) Duplicate that image (let's call it `B`) and replace all pixels inside the circle with white. To do that, create a binary mask. (see below)

3) Calculate the total # of black pixels in that image (i.e. `B`).

4) Subtract both values. That should give you the number of black pixels within the circle.

**Sample code:** I used a dummy image I had on my computer and created a logical mask with the `createMask` method from `imellipse`. That seems complicated but in your case since you have the center position and radius of the circle you can create directly your mask like I did or by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383510/matlab-mask-create-a-circular-roi-knowing-its-origin-point-with-a-certain-radiu/31384342#31384342) question/answer.

Once the mask is created, use `find` to get the linear indices of the white pixels of the mask (i.e. all of it) to replace the pixels in the circle of your original image with white pixels, which you use to calculate the difference in black pixels.

```
clc;clear;close all
A = im2bw(imread('TestCircle.png'));

imshow(A)
Center = [160 120];
Radius = 60;

%// In your case:
% Center = [MYY1 MYX1];
% Radius = round(MYR2/2);

%// Get sum in original image
TotalBlack_A = sum(sum(~A))

e = imellipse(gca, [Center(1) Center(2) Radius Radius]);

%// Create the mask
ROI = createMask(e);

%// Find white pixels
white_id = find(ROI);

%// Duplicate original image
B = A;

%// Replace only those pixels in the ROI with white
B(white_id) = 1;

%// Get new sum
NewBlack_B = sum(sum(~B))

%// Result!
BlackInRoi = TotalBlack_A - NewBlack_B
```

In this case I get this output:

```
TotalBlack_A =

      158852


NewBlack_B =

      156799


BlackInRoi =

        2053
```

For this input image:

[image]